# Build gcc with Fortran only

Tags: gcc, build, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile on OS-X gfortran only with the following configuration:

```
./configure --prefix=${INSTALL_HERE} \
--enable-checking=release \
--disable-stage1-checking \
--enable-languages=fortran \
--disable-cloog-version-check \
--disable-isl-version-check \
--disable-libstdcxx \
--enable-lto \
--disable-nls \
--with-gmp="${GMP_DIR}" \
--with-mpc="${MPC_DIR}" \
--with-mpfr="${MPFR_DIR}" \
--with-cloog="${CLOOG_DIR}" \
--with-isl="${ISL_DIR}"
```

However the end result is that I have not only `gfortran` but the whole suite, i.e. C/C++ compilers. Why does it happen considering the fact that I have `--enable-languages=fortran`?!

I only need gfortran to complement clang on OS-X.

Comment: Is this actually a problem? Why are you unhappy about having C/C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the gcc-help list:

C & C++ are mandatory for the build procedure.

https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-11/msg00052.html

Comment: well... it's was me who asked a question there ;-)

Comment: Sure, but don't put any **UPDATE** into your question next time, but create an answer.